# Difference between 公告 and 通知?

Tags: meaning, difference

通知 and 公告 both mean a notification from the authority.

But any difference? Could somebody help me figure out the difference with some concrete examples?

Comment: My idea: because 公告 has 公 in it, it is a public announcement, directed at a large number of people, e.g. via TV or newspaper. 通知 is just a notificiation, notice that can also be directed at selected individuals that can take the form of a letter, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

公告

> announcement, public announcement, proclamation, public notice

通知

> notice, inform, notify

A 公告 is a 通知 to the public.

A 通知 can be private or public.

公告 =  通知 + publicity

Answer (score 2):

I think that the "公告" is commonly used in government, to publish important thing, it is more formal. "通知" means notice, let a few people know.